How to detect "typed-in" http request?
A few years ago I found that behavior of Internet browsers changed. A new class of HTTP requests started to happen; they are HTTP requests created by the browsers when a user simply type in a web address in an URL-field and the URL is read from local history. Even though the user does not hit "Enter" to go to the page, the HTTP requests happen and the server does all the job as if the user just landed on the page. All the database queries, calculations and all that sort of jobs are done, but the output goes nowhere. When a user hits "Enter" everything is repeated again and this time the output goes to the user. So, server does its job twice. On a larger scale it is a performance issue.
Question: how to detect so called "typed-in HTTP requests" made by browser from those when the user actually goes to a page? Is there a special variable on Request.ServerVariables?
Checked Request.ServerVariables documentation.
PS. Additional question how to catch a HTTP request done through "view-source:xxxxxx"?

I tried an experiment with current versions of chrome, firefox, and safari on Mac OS Sequoia. Only safari exhibited this "prefetch" behavior, but when I pressed enter the HTTP request was not made a second time.

Thx for your time

You should think about implementing caching. This way the results are served without all those complicated calculations every time, and then you can use various techniques to go around caching when needed, including not caching those paths where you don't want it to happen. There are ton of guides how to do this online. Hope this helps.

No need to use tons of caching techniques if a web-server simply detects "type-in" HTTP request and ignores it. But if I only new how...
